# Transform 3d with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the 3D visualization of the following example is wrong. I translate background divs of 10px in Z and the foregound divs of 0px. The result is that the divs are not visualized as expected: the second background is over the first buckground, anyone can explain it?

```css
.parallax {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
}

.background {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #080;
  transform-style: preserve3d;
  transform: translateZ(-10px) rotateY(5deg);
}

.foreground {
  height: 300px;
  transform-style: preserve3d;
  transform: translateZ(0px) rotateY(5deg);
  background-color: #008;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="foreground"></div>
  
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="foreground"></div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `z-index` and `position: relative;` in your `.background` and `.foreground` elements:

```css
.parallax {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
}

.background {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #080;
  transform-style: preserve3d;
  transform: translateZ(-10px) rotateY(5deg);
}

.foreground {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 300px;
  transform-style: preserve3d;
  transform: translateZ(0px) rotateY(5deg);
  background-color: #008;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="foreground"></div>
  
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="foreground"></div>
  
</div>
```